# Fixed DIV shows elements underneath

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a fixed DIV that I have that sits at the top of a page and as the user scrolls down the page the fixed DIV moves down. When the user clicks on the fixed DIV it toggles and allows the user to upload an image.

The problem I have found is that if I have as an example a Google Map (DIV) underneath this shines through the Fixed DIV.

Example of DIV Fixed

```
<div id="flip" style="position: fixed; width: 98%;">CLICK TO ADD PHOTOS<br /><span style="font-size: 11px;">Expands to allow for uploading photo</span></div>    

<div id="panel" style="position: fixed; margin-top: 35px;width: 98%; z-index: 100;"><iframe src="upload.aspx?id=<%Response.Write(Request.QueryString["id"]); %>&type=<%Response.Write (Request.QueryString["type"]); %>" style="overflow: scroll;height: 500px; border: 0px;" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

How do I stop any DIV underneath this fixed DIV from displaying on the top of the fixed DIV?

Answer (score 0):

add `z-index: 101;` to your div with I'd `flip` to position it on top of the other div.

```
<div id="flip" style="position: fixed; width: 98%; z-index: 101;">CLICK TO ADD PHOTOS<br /><span style="font-size: 11px;">Expands to allow for uploading photo</span></div>    

<div id="panel" style="position: fixed; margin-top: 35px;width: 98%; z-index: 100;"><iframe src="upload.aspx?id=<%Response.Write(Request.QueryString["id"]); %>&type=<%Response.Write (Request.QueryString["type"]); %>" style="overflow: scroll;height: 500px; border: 0px;" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

set the z-index of your divs always higher for the ones you want underneath them. if the div you describe with the Google maps in it has a z-index of let's say 1000, set your other elements higher than 1000 in order to be on top of the ones set with a lower number.

Comment: To the underlying DIV in the body of the web page? Note I'm not showing the code here as it's just a standard DIV

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like changing the CSS z-index property would fix your problem.

```
#flip { z-index: 100; }
#panel { z-index: 50; }
```

Comment: Note the body DIV isn't shown here so do I add a z-index of a number as well?

Comment: The z-index property only applies to positioned elements. Only add it to elements with the position property applied and set to relative, absolute, or fixed.

Comment: the rule applied to #panel won't have no effect or whatsoever as the element has an inline style that will take precedence over all other css rules unless you set it as !important

Answer (score 0):

**A.** z-index could get to a really high number in certain situations. Up to 2147483647 (90000 would be enough). Try changing the element you want above everything to a *very high* number to discard this is the issue.

**B.** Switch (Invert) the order between both divs.

As you didn't provided the rest of the HTML this are two easy to test solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` CSS property would solve your problem, a div with the highest value for `z-index` property would always show in the top, so you need to add a `z-index` value for **flip** div higher than 100 *(**panel**'s `z-index` value)*

```
<div id="flip" style="position: fixed; width: 98%; z-index: 101;">CLICK TO ADD PHOTOS<br /><span style="font-size: 11px;">Expands to allow for uploading photo</span></div>    

<div id="panel" style="position: fixed; margin-top: 35px;width: 98%; z-index: 100;"><iframe src="upload.aspx?id=<%Response.Write(Request.QueryString["id"]); %>&type=<%Response.Write (Request.QueryString["type"]); %>" style="overflow: scroll;height: 500px; border: 0px;" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

Refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) for more information about `z-index` CSS property.